# Pokemon 3D offiicial server not working?

Tags: pokemon-series

I downloaded Pokemon 3D and the official server is not working.

I have tried refreshing and quitting the game but its still not working.

(version 0.48)

Comment: nintendo's servers were shut down not too long ago

Comment: @ratchetfreak: [Pokémon 3D](http://pokemon3d.net/) is not run by Nintendo.

Answer (score 1):

Pokemon 3D official server goes in and out all the time because of how many people are trying to access it. Also, Nillzz shuts down the official server when applying updates to Pokemon 3D. There is a server that is hosted by someone and is kept up all the time, you can find it here: http://pokemon3d.net/servers/

The forums are always a good place to look for updates, as they are constantly updated. You can also follow Nillzz on Twitter here: https://twitter.com/nilllzz

He is very nice and you can find other admins (darkfire, hippocrit, etc) that will try to assist you if you have any other issues with the game. Enjoy!